Proving multiple of $3^n$ can be written as square $+ 2$
How can we prove that for every $n ≥ 1$, there exist integers $x$ and $k$ such that $k\cdot 3^n = x^2 + 2$? My approach was to try using mathematical induction. Base case and inductive hypothesis is simple but I ran into trouble converting $(x^{2}+2)^{2}$ into the form a square plus 2. Feel like I'm on the wrong track anything would help.

This is a classic example of something called Hensel's lemma. You can also prove inductively that, for each $n,$ there are $a,b$ relative prime with $a^2+2b^2=3^n.$ Then use that answer to find $m$ such that $m^2+2$ is divisible by $3^n.$ It helps if you know about rings like $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-2}]$

If $k\cdot3^n=x^2+2$, then $k'\cdot3^{n+1}=\left(x+m\cdot3^n\right)^2+2$, where $m\equiv\dfrac kx\pmod3$

For the inductive step, if $k\cdot 3^n=x^2+2$ instead consider
$$(3^n\pm x)^2+2=3^{2n}\pm2\cdot x\cdot 3^n+x^2+2$$
Note that it is enough to show that $3^{n+1}$ divides one among $(x^2+2)\pm x\cdot3^n = 3^n(k\pm x)$, or equivalently that $ 3 \mid (k\pm x)$.  From the induction hypothesis we have that

$x$ isn't a multiple of $3$ and
if $k$ is a multiple of $3$ we are already done.

The remaining possibilities are that they have the same remainder when divided by $3$, in which case $k-x$ is a multiple, or else $k+x$ is.
--
P.S. Above approach is perhaps a simpler version of JW Tanner's comment.
